# VB.NET auto click url

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, click, auto

How can I open a link on a website in Visual Basic WebBrowser without a manual click?

For example:

```
Webbrowser1.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions")
```

I want to open the first video in this URL in the WebBrowser2.

Comment: What is returned from that method call?  JSON or XML?  Use the appropriate library to parse the returned data and extract the first item. You really need to implement more code for a proper question to be asked and answered.

Comment: When you load the page, find the information your need, eg HTML source, and extract it.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Webbrowser1.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions")
```

and on DocumentCompleted event.

```
For Each link As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links
   //some logic here to select links to click
   link.InvokeMember("click")
Next
```

Comment: You can't access the page until it is fully loaded. Use the [**`DocumentCompleted` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx).